# Extract approximate probability density function (pdf) in R from random sampling

Tags: r, random, probability-density

I have got `n>2` independent continuous `Random Variables(RV)`. For example say I have `4 Uniform RVs` with different set of `Upper and lowers`.

```
W~U[-1,5], X~U[0,1], Y~[0,2], Z~[0.5,2]
```

I am trying to find out the approximate PDF for the sum of these RVs i.e. for `T=W+X+Y+Z`. As I don't need any closed form solution, I have sampled `1 million points` for each of them to get `1 million samples for T`. Is it possible in R to get the approximate PDF function or a way to get approximate probability of `P(t<T)`from this samples I have drawn. For example is there a easy way I can calculate `P(0.5<T)` in R. My priority here is to get probability first even if getting the density function is not possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the `ecdf` function:

```
set.seed(123)
W <- runif(1e6, -1, 5)
X <- runif(1e6, 0, 1)
Y <- runif(1e6, 0, 2)
Z <- runif(1e6, 0.5, 2)

T <- Reduce(`+`, list(W, X, Y, Z))
cdfT <- ecdf(T)
1 - cdfT(0.5) # Pr(T > 0.5)
# [1] 0.997589
```

See [How to calculate cumulative distribution in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30860/126864) for more details.